# MeteorJS Publish/Subscribe Model on Mobile

Tags: meteor

I am using a MeteorJS to create an app for mobile phone. it will be deployed to iOS and Android.

I know the autopublish package is used to simplify database management, but it may also introduce some security concerns when using MeteorJS as a website where the endpoint is the browser and the database is on the remote server. to get around this problem you can remove the autopublish package and make better use of the Meteor.methods() function.

I was wondering if this is relevent on meteor 'native' mobile deployments, where the full stack is deployed to the device. so if a user was to load up a javascript console for the webview in the native wrapper of the standalone app on a device, the user would only be able to affect change to the device's local database (unlike the browser based version where there is a shared database).

Does that make sense? i am very new to Meteor, so i hope im not misunderstanding the concept of how Meteor works.

Answer (score 0):

**"*'native' mobile deployments, where the full stack is deployed to the device*" do not exist**.  When you deploy to ios or android, it is your client code that is wrapped with Cordova/Phonegap and deployed, your server must be deployed the same as for a browser client.

You should always remove the autopublish and insecure packages before deploying to production, for both browser and mobile clients.

The situation is the same for both browser and mobile clients.  Neither have access to a 'shared' database, both use the minimongo in memory database, which is kept updated by the ddp pub/sub protocol.

It is a credit to the Meteor developers that the developer experience using it makes it seem like you (almost) have direct access to the server db.

[This is in line with standard secure coding principles](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Secure_Coding_Principles#Principle_of_Least_privilege)

Publications publish subsets of the server db data for 2 reasons:  Security and Performance.  While there may be corner cases where you genuinely do want to publish everything, in real world apps this is likely leaking (sensitive) data, and slowing down your app by sending more than is required.

The insecure package must also be removed for the same reason, as if left in place you are allowing an attacker read/write access to your server data.